# Show that sawtooth function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Show that sawtooth function $f$ is continous, where $f$ is given by

$f(n) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    x-2n & \quad \text{if } {2n \leq{x} \leq{2n+1}}, {n \in \mathbb{Z}}\\
    2n-x & \quad \text{if } {2n-1 \leq{x} \leq{2n}}, {n \in \mathbb{Z}}
  \end{array} \right.$

---

I know saw tooth is nowhere differentiable

but nothing i can do except taking the limit around $2n^{+}$ and $2n^{-}$

$\lim_{x \to 2n^{-}} (x-2n) = 0 = \lim_{x \to 2n^{+}} (2n-x)$

which is super dumb

Comment: Actually, the sawtooth is differentiable everywhere except at the integers. Also, what you're doing with the limits is correct. You're missing the limits at $2n+1$, though.

Comment: @JavierBadia why do i need to compute limit for $2n+1$??

Comment: The points where it's not obvious that your function is continuous are the integers. You've checked the even ones, you're missing the odd ones.

Comment: If you are allowed to use a little bit of topology, then you don't need to compute any limit. You just need to check their two definition agree on the intersection and apply [Pasting Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) to glue the two definitions together.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you!! didnt learn that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$f(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    x-2n, & \quad \text{if } {2n \leq{x} \leq{2n+1}}, \;\; {n \in \mathbb{Z}}\\
    2n-x, & \quad \text{if } {2n-1 \leq{x} \leq{2n}}, \;\; {n \in \mathbb{Z}}
  \end{array} \right.$$
is not differentiable only at points $x_n=n, \;\; {n \in \mathbb{Z}},$ but everywhere continuous. You are right that $\lim\limits_{x \to 2n^{-}} f(x) = 0 = \lim\limits_{x \to 2n^{+}} f(x).$ In addition,$\lim\limits_{x \to (2n+1)^{-}} f(x) = 1 = \lim\limits_{x \to (2n+1)^{+}} f(x)$ and  $f(x)$ is continuous on every open interval $(2n,\; 2n+1).$

Comment: However, how do u even able to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to \(2n+1)^{+}}$?? Its not even part of the function??

Comment: Since $f(x)=x-2n$ for ${2n \leqslant{x} \leqslant{2n+1}}, \;\; {n \in \mathbb{Z}}$, we have $\lim\limits_{x \to (2n+1)^{-}} f(x) =\lim\limits_{x \to (2n+1)^{-}} (x-2n)=1.$     

Similarly,  $ \lim\limits_{x \to (2n+1)^{+}} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to (2n+1)^{+}} (2n+2-x)=1$ for $\;\;{2n+1 \leqslant{x} \leqslant{2n+2}}, \;\; {n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and both one-sided limits are equal to $f(2n+1)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Nothing dumb about it. In between the integers it is clearly continuous, even differentiable, so if you show the left and right limits are equal to the function at all integers, not just the evens, you are there.

Comment: so....my answer is complete???

Comment: You should also find the limit is $1$ at the odd integers, but that is basically the same as you have done for the evens.